# Tables as SQLCMD scripting variables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to compare the entries in a table (lets call it `ProductsA`), on a server (lets call it `ServerA`) against the entries in another table (`ProductsB`) on a separate server (`ServerB`). I essentially want to see which products exist in `ProductsA` that do not exist in `ProductsB`. I do not have create table permissions on `ProductsB`, or I would likely just import the items from `ServerA` onto a temporary table in `ServerB` with a flat file.

I am using the SQLCMD `:CONNECT` command to switch between servers. The problem I am having is that I cannot use a standard table variable to hold the data from `ServerA` when I switch to the other server since that variable is tied to the initial server connection and gets disposed when I `:CONNECT` to `ServerB`.

My question is, is there a way to declare a table variable as a scripting variable with `:setvar`? The table variable declaration for normal variables `:setvar ProductsInA TABLE (ID int)` does not work with the `:setvar` syntax. This leads me to believe that scripting variables cannot be tables.

Is there a way to use scripting variables to hold table data? I really only need the one ID column from `ServerA` to carry over into my query on `ServerB`, so there may be a simpler way to do this that is not occurring to me.

The query I'm trying to run looks like the following

```
:setvar ProductsInA TABLE (ID int)
:CONNECT ServerA
INSERT INTO $(ProductsInA) (ID)
(
    SELECT ID FROM DatabaseA..ProductsA
)
GO

:CONNECT ServerB
SELECT ID FROM DatabaseB..ProductsB
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT ID FROM $(ProductsInA)
)
GO
```

Thank you in advance for any replies!

Comment: Scripting variables are just strings, where the value is replaced by SQLCMD before the query is sent to SQL Server for execution. So scripting variables cannot be used as tables.

Comment: why didn't you link both servers and select normally from the two tables?

Comment: Consider using Powershell. What SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: @J.Salas ServerB is locked down extremely tight, I have next to no permissions for databases on it including the ControlServer permission required to link that server to another one

Comment: How many rows does `SELECT ID FROM DatabaseA..ProductsA` return?

Comment: @DanGuzman SQL Server 2019

Comment: @MartinSmith About 800,000

Comment: I just tested `SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 800000) FOR JSON PATH` and then taking the results of that and running `SELECT * INTO #temp FROM OPENJSON('huge string') WITH (value INT)` - SSMS syntax highlighting wasn't overly happy with the length of the string but it only took 2 seconds to run. Potentially that would be one way of getting the data into a #temp table on ServerB that you can then reference

Comment: Can you use Visual Studio? It has a nice Data Compare option

Answer (score 2):

Scripting variables are just strings, where the value is replaced by SQLCMD before the query is sent to SQL Server for execution. So scripting variables cannot be used as tables.

Below is an example C#-ish Powershell script that accomplishes the task by bulk copying the source table IDs from ServerA..DatabaseA into a temp table on ServerB, and then executes the query against ServerB..TableB and the temp table . This example writes the result output to a file instead of the console since you mentioned in comments the tables are large.

```
$connectionString1 = "Data Source=ServerA;Initial Catalog=DatabaseA;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$connectionString2 = "Data Source=ServerB;Initial Catalog=DatabaseB;Integrated Security=SSPI"

try {

    $connection1 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString1)
    $command1 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM DatabaseA..ProductsA;", $connection1)
    $connection1.Open()
    $reader1 = $command1.ExecuteReader()

    $connection2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString2)
    $command2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE #idlist(ID int NOT NULL);", $connection2)
    $connection2.Open()
    [void]$command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connection2)
    $bcp.DestinationTableName = "#idlist"
    $bcp.WriteToServer($reader1)
    $bcp.Close()
    $command2.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM DatabaseB..ProductsB WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM #idlist);"
    $reader2 = $command2.ExecuteReader()
    $sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\temp\results.txt")
    while($reader2.Read()) {
       $sw.WriteLine($reader2[0]) 
    }
    $connection1.Close()
    $connection2.Close()
    $sw.Close()

}
catch {
    throw
}
```